# Limits of a Transfer Function as s approaches infinity

Tags: limits

If you were to evaluate the limit as $s$ goes to infinity of the transfer function:

$$T(s) = {3s^2\left(s^2+36\right) \over s^4 + 2.344s^3 + 1.824s^2 + 0.987}$$

Why is the answer $3$? Is it due to the numerator having an $s$ term with a power of $4$ with $3$ as the coefficient, and the denominator has an $s$ term with power $4$ with a coefficient of $1$? Do you just ignore all the other terms?

EDIT: I am now trying to evaluate the limit as $s$ goes to zero.

It has been suggested to directly substitute $s = 0$ into the Transfer Function.

$$T(s) = {3(0)^2\left((0)^2+36\right) \over (0)^4 + 2.344(0)^3 + 1.824(0)^2 + 0.987}$$

However the answer is $$=3(s)^2 {36\over 0.987}$$

Why is there still an s term in the answer after the substitution.

EDIT 2:

Please refer to original question (1.9)(Ignore the second T(s) shown - the one with $s^5$, it is for another question) and solution provided. The solution provided may be wrong.

[image: question]

[image: answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the rational function has a denominator and numerator of same degrees, the limit as $s \to \infty$ is the quotient of the numerator's leading coefficient and the denominator's leading coefficient. This is because as you increase towards $\infty$, terms other than leading one become negligible to the final result.

And thusly, if the degree of the numerator is larger, the limit approaches $\infty$. If the degree of the denominator is larger then the limit approaches $0$.

Comment: how would it change if the limit was as s tends to zero? I am left with an s term in the answer but do not understand, if I have to replace every s term with a zero

Comment: @lgdl.y You can use direct substitution to evaluate the limit in your specific case because it does not lead to an undefined answer. But other techniques such as L'Hopital can be used when you have $0/0$ or  other indeterminate cases.

Comment: thank you for the edit. Please see new edit, formatted correctly too

Comment: @lgdl.y How did you get that answer? The numerator is $0$ if you take the limit as $s \to 0$... anything multiplied by $0$ is $0$.

Comment: I have posted the solution, I got the answer from the book. Is it wrong? Appreciate the help

Comment: @lgdl.y And $\lim_{s\to0} 109.4s^2 = 0$.

Comment: ok, so the limit is still actually zero, they just arbitrarily choose to figure out a constant of $s^2$

Comment: I have no idea why they did that because there should be no equal sign. If you're taking the limit of some variable $s$, your evaluated result should not include that variable $s$ if you use equality.

Answer (score 1):

write your term as $$\frac{s^4(3+\frac{108}{s^2})}{s^4(1+\frac{2.344}{s}+\frac{1.824}{s^2}+\frac{0.987}{s^4})}$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that, by dividing numerator and denominator by $s^4$, one gets
$$
\frac{3s^2(s^2+36)}{s^4 + 2.344s^3 + 1.824s^2 + 0.987}=\frac{3+\frac{108}{s^2}}{1 + \frac{2.344}{s}+ \frac{1.824}{s^2} + \frac{0.987}{s^4}}
$$ then let $s \to \infty$.